# Selector returning a 404

Tags: angular

Had an odd scenario where a selector of mine is returning a 404.

```
<app-timeout-dialog #timeout
                [visible]="(timeoutVisibleState$ | async).visible"
                [searchCode]="(timeoutVisibleState$ | async).searchCode"></app-timeout-dialog>
```

For some reason the the [visible] and [searchCode] there it is returning a 404 when I try to access my app (the default page returns a 404). If I remove those two then it works just fine. I know the .visible returns the value false whenever I try to add it to the front end.

Here is where I am getting the timeoutVisibleState$:

```
public timeoutVisibleState$ = this.store.select(fromDialog.timeoutState);
```

This is the function that gets called every X amount of time:

```
showTimeoutDialog() {
this.store.dispatch(new UpdateTimeoutDialogStateAction({visible: true, searchCode: this.searchCode}));
this.timeoutShown = true;
}
```

I know for sure that I am correctly getting the correct search code because I console.log this.searchcode when the search button is pressed.

Comment: Could you use https://stackblitz.com to create an [mcve] and post the link? That would go a long way for others to try to help you.